# ios abort didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to abort this method when a certain condition is not met, how should I do it?

I dont use tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. I think it is possible to combine these two methods to prevent certain rows to be selected and be pushed into another ViewController?

---

EDIT:

Guys, thank you very much.

Now this code works perfectly :

```
- (NSIndexPath*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger totalcount = [totalarr count]; //totalarr is a global mutable array.

    NSIndexPath *rowToSelect = indexPath;

    if (totalcount == 0)
    {
        rowToSelect = nil;
    }
    return rowToSelect;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is sent to the table view delegate when a row is about to be selected. Your delegate has the chance to change the selection, or cancel it entirely by returning an `NSIndexPath` object for the alternative selection, or `nil` to select nothing.

Hence, if you want to inhibit the selection of certain rows, use `tableView:t willSelectRowAtIndexPath:p`, do your check on `p`, and if you don't want that to be selected, just return `nil`. If you cancel the selection thus, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will never be called.

Don't "cancel" things inside `didXXYY` type methods if you have a chance to do so in `willXXYY`. The `did` implies that the selection has been committed; UIKit might have displayed this, other event listeners might have responded, etc. It can easily lead to weird behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, implement `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Return the provided index path when you want the row to be selectable, and return nil otherwise.